# Javascript REGEX for finding a substring between two strings

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a JS function to find and  a substring(REGEX) of the following text. Im trying to change the color of the options in a would you rather question.

**String Example**

```
Would you rather be on a survival reality show or dating game show?
```

**Solution Example**

```
Would you rather <span class="highlight1"> be on a survival reality show </span> or <span class="highlight2"> dating game show? </span>
```

Ive tried the below code but i cant figure our the REGEX.

HTML:

```
<div class="question">
<p>Would you rather be on a survival reality show or dating game show?</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red{color:red;}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.question').html(function(_, html){
        return html.replace(**WHAT DO I PUT HERE**, '<span class="red">$1</span>');   
     });});
```

REGEX - does not work in above code.

```
(?<=Would you rather)(.*)(?=or) 1st Part

(?<=or)(.*)(?=) 2nd Part
```

I need some help to make these regular expressions work in JS. they dont seem to do anything. Im such a noob.

Comment: JS regex syntax is `html.replace(/your-regex-here/, '<span class="red">$1</span>');` I don't want what has to be a result, so just this basic advice.

Comment: It's the /your-regex-here/ part that I just dont get.... How can i convert (?<=Would you rather)(.*)(?=or) to Regex that JS would understand.

Comment: how the result should looks? You're looking 2 parts in your regex, but takes just one inside span... please add any examples or strings and results.

Comment: Lets look at the first part. (?<=Would you rather)(.*)(?=or) I'll like to apply this to html.replace(/your-regex-here/, '<span class="red">$1</span>');  

but the syntax is not accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex for gaining just the first part of question could be

```
/^Would you rather(.*)(:? or .*)$/
                       ^^ find 'or' and the rest of question
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9pwbj58g/1/

I don't know, what you want to do with that, instead of `alert` can be any `$(this).html(...)` or something.

To change both parts, eg.

```
/^(Would you rather)(.*)(:? or )([^?]+)\?$/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9pwbj58g/2/

Comment: +1... I didn't see unformatted `solution example` in your question, so it's why I tried 1st code... you need the second one, right? Glad to help you!

Comment: Yes the second one did it for me! I dont know how you guys write regex. I get blocked everytime with it

Comment: @DuvonLawrence: many attempts in history and after thousands regex it's a routine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let res = html.replace(/(?<=Would you rather)(.*)(?=or)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
res = html.replace(/(?<=or)(.*)(?=)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
return res;
```

I guess that's what are you trying to achieve. Read: [RegExp in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = 'Would you rather be on a survival reality show or dating game show?'
html.replace(/^(Would you rather\s)(.*)(\sor\s)(.*)\?$/g,`$1<span class="red">$2</span>$3<span class="red">$4</span>?`)
```

Comment: Please provide more information about the methods you're using, so people can benefit from your answer in the future.

Comment: @Notflip how about this?[String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Switching_words_in_a_string)

Comment: You can add it to your answer.